# mysql date range ignores end date in result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not getting result till '2013-07-31' instead I get one day before endDate.
How can I add one day in '2013-07-31'

```
select * from employee 
where admissiondate>='2013-01-01' 
and admissiondate<='2013-07-31'
```

Comment: Is `admissiondate` a `datetime` column or `date`?

Comment: it is datetime column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2013-07-31 12:00:00` is neither smaller nor exactly equal to `2013-07-31`.

To fix it either you strip off the time part from your `datetime` column using `date()`

```
select * from employee 
where date(admissiondate) between '2013-01-01' and '2013-07-31'
```

But that won't make use of indexes. Or add a time part like this

```
select * from employee 
where admissiondate >= '2013-01-01' 
and admissiondate <= '2013-07-31 23:59:59'
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50cf9/4)

Comment: in runtime I am getting '2013-07-31' I cannot change it to '2013-08-01'

Comment: is there anything like admissiondate < '2013-08-01'+1

Comment: try `'2013-07-31' + interval 1 day`

Comment: Why can't you change the value after you get it?

Comment: use the DATE_ADD() function

Comment: yes. I can change it by adding ONLY one day in it.  How to do that?

Comment: DATE_ADD/ interval did not help either.

Comment: @AmitG: I added a SQLFiddle. Can you please demonstrate your problems in there?

Answer (score 1):

Use the DATE_ADD() function ...

[MySQL DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: DATE_ADD() doesn't help. I tried like select * from employee 
where admissiondate>='2013-01-01' 
and admissiondate<=DATE_ADD('2013-07-31',interval 1 day) with no expected output.